# Replace specific line of file when line number is stored as a variable (bash)

Tags: bash

I have a number stored in the variable `order`.
I want to insert the contents of the variable `contents` at the line number stored in `order` in a file.

I found a bunch of different ways of doing it if the number is a static, but in this case the variable is changed in each iteration in a while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `sed "${order}s/SEARCH_PATTERN/REPLACE_PATTERN/"`. You can use `.*` as a search pattern if you want to replace the line.

For example to replace the contents of the lines 3, 4 and 5 with "LINE3", "LINE4" or "LINE5" accordingly:

```
for order in {3..5}
do 
    sed -i "${order}s/.*/LINE${order}/" file.txt
done
```